# How to login to docker in Jenkins declarative syntax?

Tags: jenkins

My objective is to pull/push images from private repositories on DockerHub using declarative syntax.

I've configured my credentials with id `xxxxxxxxxxx`.   I understand I can do this with the programmatic syntax [as shown here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#custom-registry), but **how can I do it in declarative so I maintain the useful overview of the CI process?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `script {}` block as a declarative step to wrap anything that would otherwise only run in scripted pipelines.  e.g. (untested)

```
stages {
    stage('Example') {
        steps {
            script {
                docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'credentials-id') {

                    def customImage = docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}")

                    /* Push the container to the custom Registry */
                    customImage.push()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an account wit my registery but i only have uername/password. How can I get the credentials-id?

Comment: @H.Z. When you create the credential in Jenkins you assign the ID yourself -- see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/