# How build a dockerfile using base image from private registry?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image and push it to private registry. I have dockerfile, where the FROM is poiting to private docker registry image. When I try to build the image using the dockerfile I'm getting **Error Status: 400 Unauthorized** . I tried logging to private registry from commandline and then run the dockerfile. But still having the same issue. Anyone suggest on this

Comment: After `docker login` have you tried to pull that base image from command line manually. Does it worked. The `error 400 unauthorized` means some problem with the login credentials.

Comment: I did the same, it was working from my local. But when using from jenkins, I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log in from the same machine where you want to build the docker image.

In the case of AWS ECS, you can try this with Docker build.

```
 $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-west-2) && docker build -t myimage .
```

in case of Dockerhub

```
docker login -u="your_username" -p="your_pass" && docker build -t abc .
```

But one should aboide plain text credentials you can the [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) for more secure way and [Getting rid of Docker plain text credentials](https://hackernoon.com/getting-rid-of-docker-plain-text-credentials-88309e07640d)

If you want to pull using Jenkins that better to prefer this approach.

```
 docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'credentials-id') {
```

[How to login to docker in Jenkins declarative syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389063/how-to-login-to-docker-in-jenkins-declarative-syntax)

Comment: @Prasith better to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389063/how-to-login-to-docker-in-jenkins-declarative-syntax